# n-digit Verification Code Generator

Tags: random, scala

This is a verification code generator, which generates n-digit numeric strings. (code can be `0000`, so I chose `String` as a return type rather than `Int` or `Long`.)

It'll be great if anyone review this code and suggest more elegant or scalaish solution.

```
import scala.util.Random

object VerificationCodeGenerator {
  val rand = new Random

  def generate(digit: Int): String = {
    val sb = new StringBuilder
    for (i <- 1 to digit) {
      sb.append(rand.nextInt(10))
    }
    sb.toString()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if your number of digits is always going to be less than about 10, then you can use a single random operation and a string format, to do all the work without the loop.

Consider a method like:

```
def generate(digit: Int): String = {
    var randVal = rand.nextInt(math.pow(10, digit).toInt)
    var fmt = "%0" + digit + "d"
    fmt.format(randVal)
}
```

The randVal pulls a value with the limited number of digits (perhaps fewer than the limit). The format operation 0-pads the value to the right number, though.

This is not so much a scala way of doing it, but it is closer, and probably more efficient.

I would consider creating instances to handle each length of digits to avoid having to create the format each time, though.

See it [running in ideone](http://ideone.com/S2SBv3)

Comment: In the general case, use either [`BigInteger`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2290057/1157100) or concatenate several generated strings.

Answer (score 7):

A shorter, more functional and perhaps more elegant way to do it is:

```
def generate(digits:Int):String = {
  (1 to digits) map(_=>rand.nextInt(10)) mkString("")
}
```

This code doesn't use a mutable object (`StringBuilder`).

One more way I can think of is:

```
def generate(digits:Int):String = {
  (for { i <- 1 to digits } yield rand.nextInt(10)) mkString("")
}
```

Slightly longer, essentially the same as first.

Answer (score 2):

A concise and idiomatic solution:

```
def generate(digits: Int): String = 
  List.fill(digits)(rand.nextInt(10)).mkString
```

Comment: Iterator may give you slightly more performance than List.